# Excel 2010 VBA Parsing XML - Don't understand where Nodelist.Item is being found

Tags: xml, excel, vba, xml-parsing

I'm working through borrowed code to understand how it parses XML and how bits of data are being found. I've very new to XML and parsing so apologies in advance for this basic question.

When I look at `oNodelist2` in the Watch window I can see it has `Item(1)`, `Item(2)`, `Item(3)` and `Item(4)` but I don't understand:

1. Where is `Item(0)` (which I think is where it should be seeking "@contextRef")?
2. Where is the value of `strContextID = 'I2013Q4'` being found?

   ```
   Sub tester2()

   Dim oInstance As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
   Dim m_strUSGAAP_TaxonomyVersion As String
   Dim m_strInvest_TaxonomyVersion As String
   Dim m_strDEI_TaxonomyVersion As String

   Dim oNodelist2 As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
   Dim strContextID As String
   Dim i As Long

   Set oInstance = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
   oInstance.async = False
   oInstance.validateOnParse = False
   oInstance.Load "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1143908/000114390813000035/ck0001143908-20130831.xml"

   m_strUSGAAP_TaxonomyVersion = "http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2012-01-31"
   m_strInvest_TaxonomyVersion = "http://xbrl.sec.gov/invest/2012-01-31"
   m_strDEI_TaxonomyVersion = "http://xbrl.sec.gov/dei/2012-01-31"

   oInstance.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xbrli='http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance' xmlns='http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance' xmlns:xbrldi='http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi' xmlns:us-gaap='" & m_strUSGAAP_TaxonomyVersion & "' xmlns:dei='" & m_strDEI_TaxonomyVersion & "' xmlns:currency='http://xbrl.sec.gov/currency/2012-01-31' xmlns:invest='" & m_strInvest_TaxonomyVersion & "'"

   Set oNodelist2 = oInstance.SelectNodes("//us-gaap:Assets | //us-gaap:AssetsCurrent | //us-gaap:LiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity")

   i = 0
   strContextID = oNodelist2.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("@contextRef").Text

   Debug.Print strContextID

   End Sub
   ```

Thanks in advance for any help on the above.

Also, if anyone has a rec for a good site(s) or book(s) on parsing, MSXML, DOM 6, NoteLists and NameSpaces I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "item 1", "item 2" etc is just the method used in the Watch window to show the individual items in the node list. It does not indicate anything about whether the underlying list starts at position 0, 1 or something else.

An `IXMLDOMNodeList` is zero-based so "item 1" in the Watch window would be the node accessed via `.Item(0)` You can confirm that the list is definitely zero-based is by trying to access the last item in the collection. You should find that `.Item(6)` results in an error whereas `.Item(5)` does not

The value of `strContextID` comes from the "contextRef" attribute of the first node which matched the XPath expression in the `oInstance.selectNodes` call

Comment: Thanks @barrowc.  When I look through the watch window items, do you know if I2013Q4 be one of the obvious values or would it buried in a string in the text or xml value in one of the Items?

Comment: Looks like `oNodelist2 > item 1 > attributes > item 1 > nodeValue` is the most straightforward path to that value in the Watch window. You could also see it as part of `oNodelist 2 > item 1 > xml` if you make the Value column in the Watch window wide enough but you would then have to extract the value from the XML. Using the `nodeValue` of the relevant attribute (the first method listed in this comment) is more likely to do what you want - i.e. just return the value itself